# Can the distance between jump lists and the task bar be configured in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, jumplist

Can I change the distance between the jump list and the taskbar? I would like to close the gap completely. That way I can use Joel's [X-Mouse Controls](http://joelpurra.se/Projects/X-Mouse_Controls/) without jump lists [fading away before I can select "close window"](https://superuser.com/questions/161854/send-input-to-background-window-on-mouse-over-in-windows-7/389253#comment441452_389253).

[image]

Comment: You question is not clear. Maybe a screenshot would help.

Comment: @Moab: [Screenshot one](http://www.josheinstein.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/image.png) by [Josh Einstein](http://josheinstein.com/blog/index.php/2010/03/windows-7-powershell-tip/), [screenshot two](http://www.itbusiness.ca/images/articles/Apr28/Jump2.jpg) by [itbusiness.ca](http://www.itbusiness.ca/it/client/en/home/News.asp?id=52976&PageMem=2). Both show a distinct gap between the task bar and the jump list.

Comment: I don't see how closing that little gap can help with getting to the close window in time.

Comment: @Moab: I guess you haven't enabled x-mouse, as stated in the question?

Comment: @Joel Another reason for some actual screenshots or a video of the specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hardly doubt there is a way to configure this. You can right click on the taskbar and from the Start Menu tab customize various things, including how many items there appear in a jump list. However, neither there nor anywhere else is there an option to control the appearance to that level of detail.

Looking at the programming interfaces for jump lists in [.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.jumplist.aspx) and [natively](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378460%28VS.85%29.aspx#jump_lists) there doesn't seem to be any way to configure this either.

While third-party tools such as [Jumplist Extender](http://code.google.com/p/jumplist-extender/) do allow you to do some things that aren't possible out-of-the-box, none I have ever seen, allow you to make the kind of changes you are asking for.

Still +1 for your question, because I would be really curious if this might be possible, despite the evidence suggesting otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer PersonalNexus. I was taking a shot at it. If only everything was tweakable :) Oh  right, it's called open source

Answer (score -2):

Try to change the system display theme. Worked for me.
Right-click desctop/ Personalise / "change Theme"

Comment: How does this answer the question? Include some details or a screenshot